# On the evaluation of $L^{-1}(\frac{1}{p^3+1})$

Tags: laplace-transform

> Evaluate $$L^{-1}(\frac{1}{p^3+1})$$

Any clue on this? i am absolutely getting no idea. Pls provide me some pointers related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

We have: $$L^{-1} \left[ \frac1{1+p^3} \right] = L^{-1} \left[\frac1{(1+p)(1-p+p^2)} \right] $$

Using partial fraction decomposition, we have: $$\frac13\left[ L^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{1+p}\right) -  L^{-1} \left[ \frac{p-\frac12} {(p-\frac12)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)^2}\right]  + \frac32 L^{-1} \left(\frac1{(p-\frac12)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \right)^2} \right) \right] $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thank you. Got answer as $e^{-t}-e^{-t/2}(\cos (\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}t)-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\sin (\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}t))$

Comment: You should get $$\frac13 \left[e^{-t} - e^{t/2} \cos \frac{\sqrt 3 t}2 + \sqrt 3 e^{t/2} \sin \frac{\sqrt 3 t}{2} \right]$$

Comment: this is how i did:-

$\frac{1}{p+1}- \frac{p}{p^2+p+1}= e^{-t}-e^{\frac{-t}{2}}L^{-1}({\frac{p-\frac{1}{2}}{p^2+\frac{3}{4}}})=e^{-t}-e^{\frac{-t}{2}}[\cos (\frac{\sqrt3}{2}t)-L^{-1}[(1/2)(1/\frac{\sqrt3}{2})\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}{p^2+(3/4)}]]=e^{-t}-e^{\frac{-t}{2}}[\cos (\frac{\sqrt3}{2}t)-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \sin(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}t)]$

Comment: can u pls have a look at this?

Comment: The power should be $e^{\frac{t} {2}}$. See here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Inverse+Laplace+transform+of+1%2F(1%2Bs%5E3)

Comment: made a mistake in expansion. It is $(p^-p+1)$. But i mistook it as $p^2+p+1$. Now got the exact answer.